# Connecting IP Camera to Mac's Ethernet Port

Tags: router, ethernet

I have a IP camera that I am trying to setup. First time setup has to be done using Ethernet, so I have connected the camera to my MacBook's Ethernet port.

However, I do not have physical access to the router, so I cannot just plug it in there.

How can I get the camera an IP address that I can use a web browser to navigate to?

I have tried just using Internet sharing but that is not working. I get a private IP address on the Ethernet port and I cannot find the camera at any IP address on the bridge connection.

I don't really need internet sharing, I just need to get the camera an IP address so that I can configure it for WiFi.

Comment: What model of camera?  Does its manual describe how to connect directly to a computer?

Comment: No, it does not. I guess what I'm trying to do is let my Mac be a DHCP server for the Ethernet port. I don't really need to share the connection

Comment: Does the camera have a default fallback IP, for when DHCP fails?

Comment: I don't believe so but let me check

Comment: It is a Foscam FI9821W